# Laravel wildcard subdomain per user

Tags: php, laravel, dns, laravel-5, laravel-forge

**Scenario:**
Using Laravel 5.2 / Digital Ocean / Laravel Forge (enabled wildcard domains on installing the site)

Every user has its own subdomain.

Main domain:    mydomain.com
User domain:    {user}.mydomain.com

Added a DNS record `(A) - * - ip address` to the domain.

Routes:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{user}.mydomain.com'], function () {
    return 'This user has a domain.';

    Route::get('user/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
        //
    });
});

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('pages.home');
});
```

**Problem:**
Every user subdomain will skip the `group domain` and will go into the normal `Route get '/'`. So it wont return `'This user has a domain.';`. What is going wrong?

[Laravel Docs Wildcard Subdomains](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing)

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to remove `return 'This user has a domain.';` as it will prevent this  route `user/{id}` from being registered. Second, try to add a default route to your sub-domains:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{user}.mydomain.com'], function () {

    Route::get('/', function ($user) {
        return "This user has a domain: $user";
    });

    Route::get('user/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
        //
    });
});
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

> When you create the new site via Laravel Forge, be sure to tick the
>   allow wildcard sub domains option:

[image: Laravel Forge new site screen]

> Then be sure to create a new A record in your DNS using the following
>   options, using your server's IP address, in this case you're using
>   Digital Ocean so you would enter your new record like so:

[image: DigitalOcean new A record]

> That's all you need to do, now wait for your DNS records to update and
>   then you will be able to implement routes using your subdomain like
>   so:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{user}.mydomain.com'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function ($user) {
        return 'You are visiting the sub-domain for user: '.$user;
    });
});
```

> I hope this helped! Good luck :)